# NuGet - Recursively process files in the package in install.ps1?

Tags: powershell, nuget, nuget-package

I need to be able to recurse the files in the current NuGet package in my install.ps1 file, but how can this be done?

I tried several searches, but there doesn't seem to be documentation for $package. I found [this workitem](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2863) that is closed, but the documentation for $package still doesn't seem to exist anywhere.

Can someone help me with how to access the files in the $package?